# Question with accepted answer deleted by post author

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, accepted-answer

In the last 10 hours, I've had two accepted answers that have been deleted by the (same) post author. Since my answers were the only ones and they weren't upvoted (maybe because the deletion took places minutes after my answers), the post author could delete its two questions.

Now I am not whining about the loss of reputation, but what annoys me is that I took the time to write detailled answers, which were of sufficient quality to be accepted, but they were deleted nonetheless.

What I would suggest is that in order to delete a post, the condition "has only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes" becomes "has only one answer, but that answer is not accepted and has no upvotes". I know that the post author could unaccept an answer before deleting his post, but that could be a way to remind them that stackexchange is not only a forum to ask and be answered, but also a database of content that can be used by future users.

Another suggestion: how about blocking deletion during the 24h after an answer was posted? That way, it has a chance to be upvoted.

Comment: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/users-deleting-questions-after-obtaining-answers. BTW, I agree with the comments to the post.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, thanks for pointing out this post (I quickly searched if it was already asked, but obviously not enough). If I understand correctly the first answer, I can raise a flag to ask for these post to be undeleted?

Comment: That's my understanding too (but I'm not sure *where* the flag should be raised).

Comment: By checking recently deleted answers, (https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/ + iduser), you can check the corresponding deleted questions.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link!

Comment: This is a known, annoying problem: help vampires get an answer to cheat and then delete to cover their tracks. When we catch it, we can undelete, but you can't flag and there's no automatism. Sucks. The only advise I can offer is to sherlock the question: if it's a problem dump, maybe let it sit for a while before answering.

Comment: @Raphael Well, since I can see my deleted answers, I can flag it, and I did (consequently, the corresponding post were undeleted). I just did not know this was a valid reason to flag.

Comment: I had a similar problem and raised a flag. The [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138905/decidable-specific-language) was undeleted by a moderator only to be edited and deleted again by the original poster. Any advice on how to handle these cases? As Nathaniel says, 15 reputation is not a big deal but it is quite annoying to sink a bunch of time to answer a question (and provide clarifications in the comments!) only to see it deleted by a user that is clearly abusing the system (I later found out that the question was cross posted and that the user has multiple accounts...).

Comment: @Steven, flag as many times as needed, and moderators will handle it.  If you're aware of cross-posting or multiple accounts that we haven't noticed, let us know that as well.  We do take action in response to these reports.  I'll second the link to https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/users-deleting-questions-after-obtaining-answers, including the comments there.